# can not simulate the iOS crash report sent to me

Tags: ios, crash, ios-simulator, logging, report

I sent my App to the App Store but was rejected due to some crashes. I'm trying to simulate, run the app on my device but can not see any crash log. Please help to interpret the log and give me some thoughts why I can't simulate it on my device. Sorry I'm new to iOS development.

Here is the report.

```
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x3375a366 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 202
1   WebCore                         0x3375a28c WebThreadLock + 48
2   UIKit                           0x3294ac64 -[UITextRangeImpl isEmpty] + 4
3   UIKit                           0x3294ee66 -[UITextRange(UITextSelectionAdditions) _isCaret] + 14
4   UIKit                           0x328f2c2c -[UITextSelectionView setCaretBlinks:] + 132
5   UIKit                           0x32951a0a -[UIKeyboardImpl setCaretBlinks:] + 94
6   UIKit                           0x3288799a -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 242
7   UIKit                           0x32869f1c -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 608
8   UIKit                           0x328c2e68 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:] + 944
9   UIKit                           0x328c24c0 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 660
10  UIKit                           0x328c2220 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 20
11  UIKit                           0x328aa95c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2368
12  UIKit                           0x328a9f4c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 244
13  UIKit                           0x3289e66c -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 800
14  UIKit                           0x3289e342 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 30
15  Meetings                        0x00053558 -[LoginView loadMeetings] (LoginView.m:50)
16  Foundation                      0x32d46a8a -[NSThread main] + 66
17  Foundation                      0x32dda59a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32f17c16 _pthread_start + 314
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32f17ad0 thread_start + 0
```

Here is the code requested

```
-(void) loadMeetings { 
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
  UITableViewController *myViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil]; 
  myViewController.title = @"Meetings"; 
  myViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.953 green:.965 blue:.886 alpha:1]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES]; 
  [spinner stopAnimating]; 
  [pool drain]; 
}
```

Comment: loadMeetings method in LoginView class is giving some error. 50th line to be precise.

Please provide some code

Comment: Please see code above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You're pushing a new view controller onto a navigation controller stack from a background thread. All calls to UIKit must be performed on the main thread. Check the `loadMeetings` method on `LoginView` and figure out why it's being sent on the background thread in the first place.

Comment: Look at your code and find out where you send `loadMeetings` to an instance of `LoginView`. Is that method send being performed on a background thread?

Comment: - (void) loginButtonPressed
{  
    if ([passCode.text  isEqualToString:@"password"])
    {
        [spinner startAnimating];  
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadMeetings) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Wrong Passcode!"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];        
    }
}

Comment: It's right there. You're invoking `loadMeetings` on a background thread but *it* sends messages to UIKit which can't happen on a background thread. I'm not sure why you feel that you need to use `-detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`, but you should probably just be using `[self loadMeetings];`.

Comment: I know I have an issue before that's why it's running on different thread. Now, I tried your suggestion and is loading fine. But then how to check if it is eliminated on the crash log? I checked my logs and it's not showing anything? What I am doing wrong? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I would email the app review team and follow up on your rejection. Ask them if they have steps to reproduce this particular crash. Once you have that, put the old code back in and make sure that it can be reproduced. Remove the code and make sure that the crash is gone. Then you can re-upload with relative confidence. I've found the developer relations team to be extremely helpful after app rejections.